# Creating a simple li slider (infinate or with 'rewind'/stop)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So far I've got scrolling list items on click using the code below:

```
$('li#news-back').click(function(){
        $('li.news-item').animate({
            left : '-=960px'
        });
        //$('li.news-item:first').insertAfter('li.news-item:last');
});
$('li#news-forward').click(function(){
            $('li.news-item').animate({
                left : '+=960px'
            });
            //$('li.news-item:last').inserBefore('li.news-item:first');
});
```

Each list item is 960px wide , items are floated left and only one item is shown in the container at any given time. Clicking back for forward will animate the li by their width making the next or previous visible..

The problem is that for now  there are 4 items. So I either need to add the first item to the end or the list or the last to the beginning of the list when clicked as the code I've commented out.

Watching this in firebug it seems to be rearranging the content as I hoped but it's not working so within the browser (getting some very odd results - jumping to the 3rd when the second should be visible etc).

The other solution perhaps would be to use an if statement to say (was we're manipulating the left property) - when back is click if left = 0 do nothing or alert there are no more in the list - then if forward is click to say if left = 2880 do nothing as you'll be at the end of the list..

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for this jumping effect is that your elements are relative to each other and by taking one from the front all of them are moving, below 3 working examples (I've used the same HTML and CSS for all of them)

1. Scroll between 1 and 5, stop if there's no prev or next item
2. Scroll between 1 and 5 and rewind to last or first element
3. Inifite scroll

HTML:

```
<a id="news-back" href="#">&lt;--</a>
<a id="news-forward" href="#">--&gt;</a>
<div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="item">text1</div>
        <div class="item">text2</div>
        <div class="item">text3</div>
        <div class="item">text4</div>
        <div class="item">text5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer-wrapper{width:960px;height:200px;display:block;overflow:hidden;}
#inner-wrapper{width:3840px;height:220px;position:relative;}
.item{width:960px;height:200px;display:block;float:left;position:relative;}
```

JavaScript - animate only if prev and next item exists

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var width=960;
    var current=1;
    var count=$('#inner-wrapper .item').size();
    $('#inner-wrapper').css({width:count*width});
    $('#news-back').click(function(){
        if(current>1){
            $('#inner-wrapper .item').animate({left:'+='+width+'px'},500);
            current--;
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('#news-forward').click(function(){
        if(current<count){
            $('#inner-wrapper .item').animate({left:'-='+width+'px'},500);
            current++;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

JavaScript - with rewind, if next don't exist go to first one, if prev don't exist rewind to the last item:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var width=960;
    var current=1;
    var count=$('#inner-wrapper .item').size();
    $('#inner-wrapper').css({width:count*width});
    $('#news-back').click(function(){
        if(current>1){
            $('#inner-wrapper .item').animate({left:'+='+width+'px'},500);
            current--;
        }else{
            $('#inner-wrapper .item').animate({left:'-'+(count-1)*width+'px'},500);
            current=count;
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('#news-forward').click(function(){
        if(current<count){
            $('#inner-wrapper .item').animate({left:'-='+width+'px'},500);
            current++;
        }else{
            $('#inner-wrapper .item').animate({left:'0px'},500);
            current=0;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Of course there's always a better way of doing it but this one works for me very good :)

Now the infinite:

```
$(function(){
    var width=960,sign="-";
    $("#news-back").click(function(){
        sign='+';
        scroll_me();
        return false;
    });
    $("#news-forward").click(function(){
        sign='-';
        scroll_me();
        return false;
    });

    function scroll_me(){
        if(!$("#inner-wrapper").is(':animated')){
            switch(sign){
                case('-'):
                    $("#inner-wrapper").stop(false,true).animate({left:"-="+width+"px"},500,function(){
                        $(this).css({left:0}).append(jQuery(".item",jQuery(this)).eq(0));
                    });
                break;
                default:
                    $("#inner-wrapper").css({left:'-'+width+'px'});
                    $("#inner-wrapper .item:first").before(jQuery("#inner-wrapper .item:last"));
                    $("#inner-wrapper").stop(false,true).animate({left:"+="+width+"px"},500,function(){
                        $(this).css({left:0});
                    });
                break;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Above script is scrolling the whole `#inner-wrapper` not all `.item`, it's similar but worth mentioning.

Let me know if you'll have any problems with it.

Cheers

G.

Comment: Thanks very much Greg, I'll check this out in the morning!

Comment: Just checked this quickly and it's exactly what I was after! Especially as you've given all three scenarios - Thank you very much for your help! :)